# ! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�ti) in arxiv

Tags: unicode, arxiv

I have the following LaTeX, with errors like `! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�ti)`. If I put \UseRawInputEncoding at the beginning of the document, it then compiles without errors locally, but when trying to upload it to arXiv, I still encounter the following error ! Undefined control sequence.

```
l.1 \UseRawInputEncoding

?
! Emergency stop.
```

and

```
! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (\xe1ti).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.169 \begin{document}

?
! Emergency stop.
...
```

How can I solve this in the arXiv source compiler?

Comment: you shouldn't use `\UseRawInputEncoding`. Instead correct the invalid utf8.

Comment: The document is about 100 pages, is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: `\UseRawInputEncoding` disables all of latex's encoding support, it has very specific uses for compatibility with ancient code implementing its own encoding support but basically breaks latex by design.  It is impossible to tell you how to fix your code if you show no example. it may simply be a case of saving the file with the correct encoding option in your editor. Editors are unlikely to save incorrect utf-8 but if you save it as latin 1 and say it is utf-8 you will get errors as shown

Comment: did you have the text `áti` somewhere in your document?

Answer (score 3):

Never use `\UseRawInputEncoding` unless you are using some pre-latex2e encoding system and you need to disable LaTeX's text encoding support.

`! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (\xe1ti).`

Isn't actually a LaTeX message, (there is no `\xe`) command. I suspect the message is

`! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (áti).`

which may show as

`! LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence (�ti).`

Or (I assume) show as `\xe1` in your editor or terminal which is using a `\x..` convention to show non-ascii bytes as hexadecimal codes such as E1 here.

`á` in the 8 bit Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) encoding is the byte hex E1.

Your file has this byte but the UTF-8 encoding of `á` is should be the two bytes hex C3 A1 and isolated E1 byte can never start a UTF-8 multi-byte encoding of a character.

So the error is telling you that your file is encoded as latin-1 but it is being treated as UTF-8. so either re-save as UTF-8 in your editor or add

`\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`

to tell LaTeX it is Latin-1 not UTF-8.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! If I change to `latin1` the encoding I got the following error `! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\protect
l.77 ...}{Convergencia d\'ebil$^{*}$}{teo.1.14}{}}`

Comment: @JoseManueldeFrutos delete your .aux and .toc files. let latex regenerate